# How to customize CalendarKit with WeekView?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, eventkit, calendarkit

I'm using the https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit library to show all events in the calendar.

this library is amazing & it's working fine.

Now, the problem is it's only available with **Day View**.

In my project requirements are **DayView** & **WeekView**

***ScreenShot 1: Day View (Default)***

Which is working fine.

[image: Day View]

What I want to achieve with this library is **WeekView**
Check the below screenshot.

***ScreenShot 2: Week View (Default)***

I've searched many libraries but none of them supports the same UI.

**Is there any solution or can we achieve it same UI?**

[image]

Comment: no answer?
Hey @ketan did you find a solution?

Comment: @MohsenFard Yes, I've used the **https://github.com/zjfjack/JZCalendarWeekView** library.

Comment: Great Thanks  Also I found https://github.com/kvyatkovskys/KVKCalendar, may be useful for others